# Blueimp file uploader implementation with Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, blueimp

I am trying to use blueimp file uploader with Node.js backend . Following the instructions [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup)

And under Node.js instructions , it says , execute via :

```
./node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js
```

I do not understand , when and where to execute this server.js file ?

Also , editing the main.js file and writing the necessary route , as mentioned in the documentation , did not help . I am not able to work it out , and request the developers to provide with a working example of blueimp with Node.js

Comment: Install the package and run that command

Comment: I surely did that , can you try and tell me if you get any results?

Comment: No. Instead, could you try it, tell us how you tried it, and what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery File Upload is a pretty capable file uploader with some nice features, but I've found its documentation to be lacking.

There are really two components to jQuery File Upload: the front-end scripts and stylesheets, and the back-end endpoints to support it.

What you're asking about specifically are the back-end endpoints, and I think there are better packages to use.  You're using `blueimp-file-upload-node`, which contains a LOT of stuff you don't need for a Node implementation, such as PHP and Python implementations, as well as front-end examples.

I recommend you look at `jquery-file-upload-middleware` instead.  It provides Express/Connect middleware, and has better documentation.  You'll still need to set up the front-end scripts per jQuery-File-Upload documetnation, but this will handle all the back-end for you.